Selecting one row on Room Database Android Compose
I have this model
data class MomentDate(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String,
    val momentId: String,
    val date: Date,
    val note: String
)

then I want to query one row like this:
    @Query("SELECT MAX(date) FROM moment_date_tbl where momentId = :momentId")
    suspend fun getLastMomentDateByMomentId(momentId: String): Date

here is my Repository:
    suspend fun getLastMomentDateByMomentId(momentId: String): Date = momentDao.getLastMomentDateByMomentId(momentId)

So,
actually in the UI.
there are a lot of momentId,
then I want to map the momentId with the latestDate get from the repository.
can anybody help me how to mapping it <momentId,latestDate>
because for select query, a lot of tutorial says it needs to use liveData,
and their example always a multiple row, not a single row like my case.
Please Help.

You already marked it suspend so it doesn’t need to (and shouldn’t) be LiveData. Does this code not work? I’m a bit rusty but it looks right to me.

Hi @Tenfour04, when I want to apply it on screen file, it needs to be suspend too.
and we cannot change the function for @ composable to be suspend right?

Sorry, I don’t understand what you’re saying. Are you saying you don’t know how to use a suspend function from a Composable function? You can get the value using produceState.

@HaryaKumuda Please edit your post and also include the Composable where you want to display the data. Also, do you use a ViewModel class?
